# pygame menu does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

For the following code, there is a problem. I am creating a main menu for my game. There are two options "Start game" and "Quit". The problem I have is that when I want to click on start game, nothing happens.

I get an error message saying: "'module' object has no attribute 'start'. I don't know what that means.

I have another called "bs" (bubble shooter). This is my main code file. When I click start of the menu file, how do I get it to go on to the bs file to play the game? Thanks for the help!

```
import pygame, os, random, math

WINDOWWIDTH  = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
STARTX = WINDOWWIDTH / 2
STARTY = WINDOWHEIGHT - 27
BLUE = (0,0,205)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,205)
upper_border = pygame.Rect(12,44,448,20) #done this
right_border = pygame.Rect(440,60,20,448) #done this
left_border = pygame.Rect(12,60,20,648) # done this
down_border = pygame.Rect(12,280,448,20) #done this

class Option:

hovered = False

def __init__(self, text, pos):
    self.text = text
    self.pos = pos
    self.set_rect()
    self.draw()

def draw(self):
    self.set_rend()
    screen.blit(self.rend, self.rect)

def set_rend(self):
    self.rend = menu_font.render(self.text, True, self.get_color())

def get_color(self):
    if self.hovered:
        return (255, 255, 255)
    else:
        return (100, 100, 100)

def set_rect(self):
    self.set_rend()
    self.rect = self.rend.get_rect()
    self.rect.topleft = self.pos

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 320))
menu_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
options = [Option("START GAME", (140, 105)), Option("QUIT", (205, 205))]
while True:
    pygame.event.pump()
    for option in options:
     if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        option.hovered = True
    else:
        option.hovered = False
    option.draw()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
        for option in options:
            if option.hovered and option.text == "START GAME":
                pygame.start()


pygame.display.update()
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,upper_border)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,right_border)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,left_border)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,down_border)
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message refers to this line:

```
pygame.start()
```

Here `pygame` is a module, and doesn't have an attribute `start`. Instead, you need to call whatever function the rest of your game is in, for example:

```
import bs

...

if option.hovered and option.text == "START GAME":
    bs.start()
```